# Using node JS to retrieve twitter from user input from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to using nodeJS and npm modules.

Using the module `twit`, I can do a GET request to the Twitter API and search tweets.

```
var Twit = require('twit')

var T = new Twit({ `login details`})

T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'banana since:2011-07-11', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

I am trying to build a simple user browser page, where a user can enter their own query parameters. I understand that modules are server side, and we can't use them on the browser. I also can't use `browserify` because twitter uses Oauth method which means you can't access it from the browser.

Is there a way to pass query parameters from the browser back to the server code, and then to pass that result back to the browser?

```
T.get('search/tweets', { q: {user options}, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

We can use `socket.io` for the streaming twitter data, but how can I use it for the REST API?

Comment: 1) how are you planning to develop the client-side
2) you want to use WebSocket explicitly or not? 
3) are you going to use javascript client-side framework?

Comment: 1) the client side is just plain javascript with an input form that the user can put in keywords. 2) i don't know about websocket - will it help? 3) just plain javscript - it's just a personal project to get it working

Comment: you are using `express` on nodejs?

Comment: yes I am using express

Comment: `Is there a way to pass query parameters from the browser back to the server code, and then to pass that result back to the browser?` Without leaving the page, this is called AJAX, and you best use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for this.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG , but twitter won’t allow access to the api from the browser

Comment: I know, that's not what I was suggesting. You need to write an express route that makes a request to the twitter API and sends back the result. Then you need to send a request to that express route from the browser (using fetch). Your express app will essentially act as proxy for the browser's request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Nodejs

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const Twit = require('twit');

...
const T = new Twit(LOGIN_DETAILS);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post('/search', function (req, res, next) {
  T.get('search/tweets', {q: req.body.searchQuery, count: 100}, function (err, data, response) {
    return res.json({
      data: data
    });
  });
});
```

## Client Side

```
...    
$.ajax({
  url: "{API_URL}/search",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    searchQuery: SearchQuery
  }),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    // do something with the response
  }
});
```

$ is jQuery, read more about [jquery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)